# Error Summing a Scientific and Decimal

Tags: java

> 1.496E11 - 0.0059 = 1.495999999999941E11
>
> (0.0059)+1.496E11 = 1.496000000000059E11

Note that the first answer is incorrect, whereas the second one is correct. What formatting do I use so java recognizes a negative decimal as the decimal it is, and doesn't assume that it is E11?

Both variables are doubles

Comment: I'm...not 100% convinced that the first answer is wrong, actually.

Comment: What's incorrect about the first answer? As in, what' result do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

I believe both of these answers are, in fact, correct.  Could you explain what you expect from the first answer that you disagree with?

Answer (score 0):

According to `bc`:

```
(1.496*10^11 - .0059) / 10^11 -> 1.495999999999941

(.0049 + 1.496*10^11) / 10^11 -> 1.496000000000049
```

They both look correct to as many decimal places as you have any right to expect.